# Does a.e. convergence imply the boundedness in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n : I = (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions.
If
$f_n \to 0 \text{ a.e.,}$
does it imply that
$\text{$f_n$ is bounded in $L^1(I)$?} $
Can someone explain me or give me examples, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $f_n = n^3 \chi_{(0,1/n)}(x)$. Then $f_n(x) \to 0$ for **every** $x \in (0,1)$ but $\|f_n\|_1 = n^2$.

Answer (score 1):

It does not. For instance, $f_n=n^21_{(0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ is a counterexample.